# Track moved issue from another project in jira

Tags: jira-agile

I am currently working on developing Jira Query Language (JQL) queries to track historical project changes. Specifically, I would like to identify issues that were previously in another project. After exploring the Jira documentation and attempting various queries, I have not found a straightforward way to achieve this using the "WAS" operator.

`project = "DestinationProject" AND project CHANGED FROM "SourceProject" TO "DestinationProject"`

any recommended approach or an alternative method?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to introduce a custom field that tracks the *original project name*.

You could write a Jira automation that would populate this field when the issue is created.

Then, if you want to know if the project changed for an issue you would compare the *original project name* field with the current project.